# Animated gif freezes in UpdateProgress in IE8

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using update progess to show the animated gif saying "Loading..". I am testing in IE 8 and the animation freezes.

I have come to know that IE 6 & 8 have a bug to handle this and have found certain supportive links such as [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2004/Dec/27/Animated-GIF-images-in-hidden-page-elements) and [here as well](http://forums.asp.net/t/1373122.aspx), but i'm not sure how to apply in update progress to resolve my issue?

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, the browser's processor was actually pegging out due to 
[KB 2000262](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000262), there is a fix, if this is your problem:

[UpdatePanel Async Postsback slow in IE…Part 3](http://blog.devlpr.net/2009/09/01/updatepanel-async-postsback-slow-in-ie-part-3)