# Show a busy indicator in a DIV with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, busyindicator

I have an animated .gif that I want to use as a busy indicator. This busy indicator will be used while some content is loading.

Once loaded, the content will appear within a div. While the content is loading, I want to basically have a semi-transparent layer over the existing content that also shows my animated **`.GIF`**. Currently, I have the following:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="contentArea">
    Loaded content will go here
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Load Latest Content" onclick="loadContent();" />
</div>
```

And the script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadContent() {
    // Show busy indicator on semi-transparent layer.
    pingWebService();
    return false;
  }
  function pingWebService() {
     $.ajax(...);
  }
  function pingWebServiceComplete() {
    // Hide busy indicator
  }
</script>
```

I have my `.ajax` call working just fine. I'm just not sure how to do the busy indicator part.

Comment: try block ui http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough, just like musefan said, just hide or show the div containing the image. Here's a contrived [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4AQx6/2/).

Answer (score 0):

JQuery only needs to show/hide the indicator image which can be done something like:

```
$("#MyBusyElement").show();
```

and

```
$("#MyBusyElement").hide();
```

The rest is down to your html/css layout. You can use transparency in CSS but this will not be supported properly by older browsers so either have a "busy" gif that has a transparent background to cover the `div`, or settle for a fully opaque cover in older browser (I would just go for this. People with old browsers should suffer!)

Comment: Careful. If you hide the animated gif, IE8 (dunno if IE9 as well) is not capable of showing the animation on a hidden-now-visible div. The image will stand still.

Comment: @Alfabravo: You mean I have to support IE too?!?! ...just kidding, I have never seen this though. Can you produce a JSFiddle (or other source) to illustrate?

Comment: My 0.02: I had a webapp where I used a "loading" animated gif. It was in a hidden div which I kept hid of visible depending on the needs. It worked fine but IE (I can't recall clearly if it was 7 or 8) showed the gif still and the client complained because it seemed like "the site had stopped working". Let me try build a jsfiddle...

Comment: Alfabravo, it seems to work for me in ie8 http://jsfiddle.net/4AQx6/2/ Maybe you're talking about ie7 ?

Comment: I got a chance to test it in ie6 and ie7, it works in both O_o. Maybe your example was an isolated incident ?

Comment: Nope, not isolated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204378/animated-gif-freezes-in-updateprogress-in-ie8

Comment: @Alfabravo: Ah, I think this is different. I too have seen an issue that freezes gifs "shown" prior to a page load/refresh. But with this AJAX approach I think this should be fine